# JPA adoption (in contrast to orphan removal )

Tags: java, jpa

Since JPA 2.0 there's the `orphanRemoval` attribute on relations which greatly simplifies updates on parent-child relations and together with cascading deletes allows to remove a whole branch of a tree and have it deleted without much hassle.

However there are also cases that might be labelled "adoption", i.e. you move a child to another parent. In those cases `orphanRemoval=true` doesn't work since the child would have to be removed from its original parent's children collection making it a temporary orphan depending on the order of remove/add operations.

According to [this EclipseLink wiki entry](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Development/JPA_2.0/orphan_removal) the JPA spec doesn't support adoption (yet).

I couldn't find any further information about this so that either means "adoption" is the wrong term (although I'd say it's pretty fitting) or this case is rare enough to not be considered in the spec and asked about on the nets.

What I'd basically like to have is orphan removal as it is just with the addition an entity that is adopted by another parent (and this parent is updated in the same transaction, e.g. by cascade updating a common root) isn't considered an orphan and thus not removed.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

The JPA specification is not clear on this. However, I bet that the actual behavior in the implementations is different from what the spec says and corresponds with your idea of adoption - it makes more sense not to remove a referenced entity. Are you sure that with your implementation (eclipselink, hibernate) it does not work as you would expect?

For example, even if you explicitely call em.remove() on an entity, hibernate does not remove it from database if it is referenced by another entity, it will simply ignore remove. I'm not sure if the same applies for orphans, but I bet so. In Eclipselink, from the [issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=249033) related to the wiki article it seems, that they resolved the issue by not deleting orphans if they are adopted by another entity.

Comment: Hmm, with since orphans normally are the owners of the relationship they could be removed without breaking consistency since the reference to the parent will be removed as well. As for the issue with EclipseLink: we saw that issue as well but fact is that if we set `orphanRemoval=false` it works as intended which leads us to the assumption that adoption is either not implemented anymore or still broken.

Comment: We're also using Hibernate but didn't test it there yet. If you have a link to a relevant documentation part, this would be nice. I didn't find anything on "adoption" besides the EclipseLink bug which leads me to the assumption that the search term might not be entirely correct.